# Graphite data and Cubism display

Tags: javascript, metrics, graphite, cubism.js

I'm trying to create a realtime dashboard for my Graphite data. I want it to show only the last hours' worth of data. I can configure Cubism to pull the data from Graphite but I'm unable to create an axis for the last hour. The Graphite data is stored with a resolution of 10 seconds for 1 hour, after one hour it is stored in 30 second resolution. When I configure Cubism to show a couple of hours all my data is squished to the left as per this question: [Why are these Cubism horizon charts squished to the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12429311/why-are-these-cubism-horizon-charts-squished-to-the-left) . I understand why this happens and therefore want to limit the time scale to the last hour only. I've looked at several examples but I'm unable to figure out how I can configure the size and steps to 1) fill the width of the screen 2) subdivide only the last hour.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can fill the width of screen with graph as follows:

Say screen width is 1400px, set canvas width and horizon width to 1400 px

The last hour could not be sub divided directly. You would have to modify cubism source to achieve that.